# Batch rename in Windows based on specific match

Tags: windows, batch-file

Say I have the following files:

- chromadenoisecfg5 - Copy.cpp
- chromadenoisecfg5 - Copy.h
- chromadenoisetest5 - Copy.cpp
- chromadenoisetest5 - Copy.h
- imagecfg5 - Copy.h

What I'd like to do is rename them to:

- chromadenoisecfg6.cpp
- chromadenoisecfg6.h
- chromadenoisetest6.cpp
- chromadenoisetest6.h
- imagecfg6.h

What I've got so far is `dir /b | findstr /i "*\b5 - Copy\b*"`, which lists all the files I'm interested in, but I'm not sure how to further process them in terms of renaming.

Furthermore, the solution revolves around the string `5 - Copy`. How can this be achieved in a generic way, with the string passed as an argument?

Comment: What is the command `findstr /i "*\b5 - Copy\b*"` supposed to match?

Comment: @aschipfl All the files from the first round of bullet points.

Comment: What should `\b` mean? there is no such expression supported by `findstr`, that's why I'm asking; I would use `findstr /I /R /C:"5 - Copy\.[~.][~.]*$"` instead...

Comment: `\b` stands for _word boundary_ in regular expressions, but now that I think of it, I may have completely mis-used it. Somehow, it did identify the files correctly though.

Comment: No, it did not, it returned file names containing `-` and such containing `Copy\`, followed by an arbitrary number if `b`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another batch one-liner:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir /B /A:-D "*5 - Copy.*"') do @(set "NAME=%%A" & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & ren "!NAME!" "!NAME:5 - Copy=6!" & endlocal)
```

This simply replaces the partial string `5 - Copy` by `6` using the [sub-string replacement syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html). For this to work, [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion) is necessary.

If you want to enter it in command prompt (`cmd`) directly, use this:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %A in ('dir /B /A:-D "*5 - Copy.*"') do @(set "NAME=%A" & cmd /V /C ren "!NAME!" "!NAME:5 - Copy=6!")
```

Comment: That's awesome! Is there a way to make it generic as in choose both the string to be replaced and its replacement?

Comment: You could assign the strings to variables in advance (like `set "SEARCH=5 - Copy" & set "REPLAC=6"`) and use them (`%SEARCH%` and `%REPLAC%`, resp.) in the code, if that's what you mean; or you could provide search and replace strings as command line arguments for the batch file (in that order and quoted!) and access them by `%~1` and `%~2`, resp....

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %A in ('dir /B /A:-D "*%~1.*"') do @(set "NAME=%A" & cmd /V /C ren "!NAME!" "!NAME:%~1=%~2!")`
rename.bat "5 - copy" "6"  
expands too -> `for /F "delims=" -D "*6 - copy.*"') do @(set "NAME=~1=7!")`
-D was unexpected at this time. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you trying this in a batch file or typed directly into command prompt? in the former case, use `%%A` rather than `%A`; in the latter case, there are no argument references `%~1` and `%~2` as such are available in batch-file only...

Comment: From a batch file called `rename.bat`. After adding the double %% as per your suggestion, the command looks like:  `for /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir /B /A:-D "*%~1.*"') do @(set "NAME=%A" & cmd /V /C ren "!NAME!" "!NAME:%%~1=%~2!")`. Please note the %% before ~1 as well, as it wasn't expanding correctly. Now it expands to: `for /F "delims=" %A in ('dir /B /A:-D "*5 - copy.*"') do @(set "NAME=5 - copy=6!" )`, but still doesn't rename the files

Comment: I'm mostly shooting in the dark here as I don't understand the syntax for the life of me. Can you please provide a working command to add to a batch file? All I did was modify your original command and trying to add the command line arguments, but it doesn't seem that straightforward

Comment: You did not use `%%A` both times; `%%~1` is wrong, it must be `%~1`. Finally, do not name your batch file like an internal command (there is a `rename` command).

Comment: Sweet! I can confirm that after fixing the above everything works as expected. Thanks a lot, @aschipfl!

Comment: You're welcome! Please consider to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer -- given it is the one that helped you most...

Answer (score 0):

Batch oneliner - UNTESTED:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %A in ('dir /B') do for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=-. " %a in ("%A") do ren %A %a.%c
```

Comment: This expands to the following and seems to only remove extensions.  
d:\tests\chromadenoisetest>for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=-. " %a in ("chromadenoisecfg5.cpp") do ren chromadenoisecfg5.cpp %a.%c  
d:\tests\chromadenoisetest>ren chromadenoisecfg5.cpp chromadenoisecfg5.

Comment: There must be quotes in the `ren` command line: `ren "%A" "%a.%c"`. Furthermore, there is no need to define the `.` as delimiter, `"tokens=1 delims=- " is sufficient when the `ren` command line is changed to `ren "%A" "%a%~xA"`. But anyway, all this does still not replace the `5` in the file names by `6`...